# NodeJS requiring library, performance issue?

Tags: arrays, node.js

Normally I require files with this way:

```
async = require('async')
```

But I want to call like this:

tools.js:

```
async = require('async')
exports.async = async
```

other.js

```
tools.async.parallel([......
```

Is this causes performance problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no performance problems with passing a single instance of the async module around.  `tools.async.parallel([...])` is slightly slower to run than a locally assigned `async.parallel([...])`, but that difference is likely immaterial.

On the other hand, `async = require('async')` caches the first loaded module, so there is little issue with just using the `require('async')` again.

A common design goal when breaking your code into modules is to make most of your modules be reusable components.  That means that they load their own things that they need using their own `require()` statements for each other module that they depend upon.  Now, that won't necessarily be the case for every module, but it should generally be part of your design thinking to make as much resuable code as possible so you can reuse code in other projects without redesigning it.  To do that, you usually want modules to just `require()` in any dependent modules on their own as this simplifies maintenance and use.